# Emulating /etc/cron.d/ on OSX

Tags: osx, cron

On most modern unixes, cron supports individual crontab files in `/etc/cron.d`, in which each task executes as a specified user. These files automatically update the crontab once edited. They allow individual packages to install their own automated tasks without polluting a global crontab or using a user-specific crontab.

OSX doesn't appear to support this — is that true?

If so, what's the best way of implementing it? Due to the fact that I am developing on OSX, but running production code on Linux, I need to use crond rather than launchd, even if the latter has potential benefits.

Comment: This question might get better answers on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: They are often run by entries in /etc/crontab or anacrontab.

Comment: @HBruijn Fair point. I posted it here because it's very much server admin specific, and knowledge of both 'traditional' unix systems and osx would probably help in answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

On OS X you should use launchd. To implement it, I will explain with an example.

Go to folder `/Users/your-username/Library/LaunchAgents` and save there the following plist file. I named it `com.username.testscript.plist`, but feel free to change it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>com.your-username.testscript</string>

  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/Users/your-username/bin/testscript.sh</string>
  </array>

  <key>Nice</key>
  <integer>1</integer>

  <key>StartInterval</key>
  <integer>60</integer>

  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>

  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/com.your-username.testscript.err</string>

  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/com.your-username.testscript.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file is pretty self-explanatory. It will launch the command `/Users/your-username/bin/testscript.sh` every 60 seconds, will be launched at load, will save errors on `/tmp/com.username.testscript.err` and logs on `/tmp/com.username.testscript.out`.

You can also use directories `/Library/LaunchAgents/` or `/Library/LaunchDaemos/`.

Comment: I've edited the question to explain why cron really is a must, although your example will probably still come in handy anyway, so thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use crontabs as usual on OS X, with the minor difference that the per-user files are in /usr/lib/cron/tabs/. The `corontab` command knows how to access them. Note that the cron daemon doesn't run by default on OS X, but `launchd` will start it if there are any files in /usr/lib/cron/tabs/, or if /etc/crontab exists.

Speaking of `launchd`: as @jherran said, `launchd` items are the more normal way to do this sort of thing on OS X, but they're a bit different from cron jobs:

- There are two main types of `launchd` items: LaunchDaemons (which generally run as root), and LaunchAgents (which run as normal users, but only within a login session). LaunchAgents can also be installed either system-wide in /Library/LaunchAgents (where they'll run for any user that logs in) or per-user in ~/Library/LaunchAgents (where they run only for that user). LaunchDaemons can only be installed system-wide.

  By contrast, cron jobs (including per-user jobs) run independently of any login session.
- cron jobs get skipped if the computer is asleep or off at the scheduled start time. `launchd` items get run at the next opportunity (i.e. after waking, starting up, logging in, etc), although multiple missed runs will be coalesced into a single run.
- cron starts its jobs in a fire-and-forget fashion; `launchd` watches over its children, and if they crash or exit, may restart them (see the `KeepAlive` key in [man launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)) and/or clean up (i.e. kill) any subprocesses they started (see the `AbandonProcessGroup` key). If your job daemonizes itself, this can cause a lot of trouble if you don't adjust the relevant settings in the .plist file.
- `launchd` supports way more options for when an item should be launched: specific times, time intervals, many different kinds of events, *just always keep it running*... Again, see [man launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html).
- Finally, the format of the command in a launchd.plist file throws a lot of people. `launchd` doesn't run commands through a shell, so things like variable references, `~` in paths, I/O redirects, etc don't work. Also, it doesn't take a command line, it takes an "array" of words in the `ProgramArguments` key that're treated essentially as the command and its arguments. e.g. `/path/to/somecommand -xv "arg number 1" arg2 arg3 >>/tmp/somecommand.log` would be written as:

  ```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
      <string>/path/to/somecommand</string>
      <string>-xv</string>
      <string>arg number 1</string>
      <string>arg2</string>
      <string>arg3</string>
  </array>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/tmp/somecommand.log</string>
  ```

  There is also a `Program` key, but don't use it unless you understand `execvp`'s arguments well. Seriously, just don't.

  If you need to have your command interpreted by a shell, you can invoke one explicitly:

  ```
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
      <string>/bin/bash</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>~/bin/somecommand -xv "arg number 1" arg2 arg3 >>~/Desktop/somecommand.log</string>
  </array>
  ```

Comment: Well, you've definitely sold me on launchd more than I was before, and I will hopefully check it out for any future OSX-only tasks. However, as you'll see by my question edit, this one needs to be OSX/unix portable. Regarding your mention of cron, that's just user-specific crontab files, though, right? I'm after that user-independent files that tend to be application-specific, that reside in /etc/cron.d/

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood; in that case, the answer is that OS X's version of cron doesn't have that feature. But actually, I'd argue that since you'd have to do it differently on OS X anyway (adding a line to /etc/crontab rather than dropping a file in /etc/cron.d), you might as well go all the way and drop a file in /Library/LaunchDaemons instead.

Answer (score -1):

If you look in the directory `/usr/lib/cron` there is a subdirectory there called `jobs` which I can only assume is the same as `/etc/cron.d`.

Comment: Please do not answer a question with assumptions, especially when you lack any kind of detailed information, context, or references to further reading.